# Running HtmlUnit through Tomcat 7

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am attempting to use HTMLUnit to produce crawlable HTML snapshots of our ajax pages (as suggested by https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ ).  The idea is to create functionality that allows business to create snapshots either through a regular scheduled service or at their own will.

I wrote a quick POC main class to test the theory out and it worked as expected (when we view source we can see all the data needed for the Google crawler that we couldn't see before).  I am now integrating this into our application that runs on Tomcat 7 and I have an issue downloading the jquery.js from Google with the following log messages

```
2013-03-15 18:10:38,071 ERROR [author->taskExecutor-1] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage       : Error loading JavaScript from [https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js].
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <ajax.googleapis.com/173.194.67.95> != <*.googleapis.com> OR <*.googleapis.com> OR <googleapis.com>
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:228)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:149)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:130)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:495)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:62)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)

...
```

Because of this the ajax isn't being executed and the snapshot does not contain the data in the view source we wish it too.  Does anyone have a clue why this would be occurring in my Tomcat version of the code and not in my standalone main class?  Both versions are running on my local machine, one is simply in Tomcat (v7) and one as a Java App.  Both versions have the same Maven includes (see bottom).

Note:  I have tried specifying a BrowserVersion when instatiating `WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);` as I did read this will produce better results (sorry I can't remember the link).  Again this works fine in the POC but when I run this in Tomcat I I see the log "Instatiating Web Client" but no matter how long I wait it never gets to "Client Instatiated" or throws any exceptions.  I don't know if this has anything to do with not being able to download the jqeury.js though as it still works in the POC without the BrowserVersion specified.

**Here is my POC Java main method that works**

```
        OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

        try {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("http://myurl.com");

            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1500);

            File file = new File("C:\\test.html");
            FileUtils.touch(file);

            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
            writer.write(page.asXml());
            writer.flush();

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURL exception");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException occurred " +  ioe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
        }
```

**Here is my integrated version**

```
        /* Entry point for the generation */
     public void generate() {

        log.info("Beginning snapshot generation...");

        try {

            // Get the URLS
            log.info("Retrieving list of page urls");
            List<String> pageUrls = getUrlList();
            log.info("Found {} urls to generate", pageUrls.size());

            // For every url we have generate a snapshot
            for (String pageUrl: pageUrls) {
                takeSnapshot(pageUrl);
            }
            log.info("Finished generating snapshots!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception caught while generating snapshot", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Take the HTML snapshot of the url and output to the snapshot directory
     */
    private void takeSnapshot(String pagePath) {
        try {
            String fullOutputFilePath = config.getHtmlSnapshotDirectory() + File.separator
                                                        + pagePath + File.separator + HTML_SNAPSHOT_FILE_NAME;
            String pageUrl = "http://myurl.com" + pagePath;

            log.debug("Instantiating Web Client...");
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            log.debug("Client instantiated");
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(pageUrl);

            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1500);

            snapshotFile = new File(fullOutputFilePath);
            FileUtils.touch(snapshotFile);

            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(snapshotFile), "UTF-8");
            writer.write(page.asXml());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURL exception");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException occurred " +  ioe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
        }
    }
```

**Maven Dependencies**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Thanks Everyone!!!**

Comment: I have found that I can use `webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);` in an attempt to get around the SSL issue.  However, when I include this line above the other `.getOptions().set...` statemtents then the code simply hangs on this line (as it did when specifying the browser version).  Meaning I am still stuck.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So adding `webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);` was the key to fixing this.  However, I had to use the deprecated version `webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);`.

I don't know why the newer version does not work when run in Tomcat but it fixed the issue.  If anyone can provide insight into why that would be great. I am also still lost as to why setting the BrowserVersion when running Tomcat causes the application to halt.  I have asked the HtmlUnit mailing list for answers on these issues.